# How to make a view helper

Tags: php, view, zend-framework2, view-helpers

...//

## EDIT:

I have resolved my problem and I want to share the solution.
The better way to make a Zend Framework 2 Helper:

```
Step 1.
<?php

//file : App_folder/module/Module_name/src/Module_name/View/Helper/SayHello.php

namespace Application\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class SayHello extends AbstractHelper{

    public function __invoke($name = 'Unnamed'){
        return "Hello $name,";
    }
}

?>
```

Step 2.

```
    <?php
    //file : App_folder/module/Module_name/Module.php

     public function getViewHelperConfig()
        {
            return array(
                'factories' => array(
                    // the array key is the name of the invoke function that is called from view
                    'sayHello' => function($name) {
                        return new SayHello($name);
                    },
                ),
            );
        }
?>
```

Step 3.

```
<?php
//file : App_folder/module/Module_name/view/Module_name/index/index.phtml

 $this->sayHello('Dimitri');
?>
```

Thanks you all for your helping.

Comment: If you find a solution to your own question please post an *answer* rather than edit your original post. Without looking at the edit history; this question will not be any help to others who might have the same issue in the future.

Comment: Also `$name` in `Module.php` is an instance of the `ViewPluginManager` (not a string). You then pass it into a *non-existent* constructor : `return new SayHello($name);`. This should be just `return new SayHello();` Or even better; create it as an `invokable` rather than via a closure.

Comment: Dimi, as @AlexP said, you have to post the result as an answer, or accept and existing one. Please, write an answer and rollback the edit so the question stays as you posted it at first. otherwise the question could get deleted since it is not an actual question and it is not useful to future users

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `ViewHelper` is a simple task and it is divided in 2-3 steps, depending on your needs. Always the first step is to actually create a `ViewHelper` and that's where you have to make your first decisions.

1. Does your `ViewHelper` have dependencies? If yes, you'll need a `__construct()` function
2. Does your `ViewHelper` need arguments? If yes, you'll need to have arguments for your `__invoke()` function

Once you've evaluated both points, you write the `ViewHelper`

```
<?php
// FileName: /module/Application/src/Application/View/Helper/MyHelper.php
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class MyHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    // If you have dependencies:
    public function __construct(DependencyInterface $dependency)
    {
        // store dependency as a local property inside class
    }

    // Put arguments if you need them, if not leave them blank
    public function __invoke($arg1, $arg2, ..., $argN)
    {
        // Have a string being returned directly
        // return 'some string';

        // Or you could return a rendered view template and pass view variables
        // return $this->getView()->render('foo/bar', array(
        //     $arg1, $arg2, ..., $argN
        // ));
    }
}
```

The second thing you have to do is to register this `ViewHelper` to the `ViewHelperManager`. If you have no dependencies, you put it up under the `invokables` configuration, if you do have dependencies, it will become a `factories` entry.

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'MyHelper' => 'Application\View\Helper\MyHelper'
        ),
        // or if it has dependencies
        'factories' => array(
            'MyHelper' => function($viewHelperManager) {
                $serviceLocator = $viewHelperManager->getServiceLocator();
                $dependency     = $serviceLocator->get('SomeDependency');

                return new MyHelper($dependency);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

And then you're able to use your `ViewHelper` via `$this->myHelper()` inside your view files. Btw it doesn't matter if you camelcase your configuration for the `ViewHelper` name because it will be lower-cased internally. So `$this->MyHelper()` equals `$this->myhelper()` and `MyHelper` equals `myhelper`.